# Does Xcode have a way to jump to the "type declaration" for a variable?

Tags: swift, xcode, appcode

Assume I have the following swift code...

```
let myFooInstance = Utils.createFooInstance() // variable type is `Foo`
```

... and I want to quickly jump to the type declaration for `myFooInstance` (ie navigate to the source code for `Foo`).

In AppCode I can simply `[shift]+[cmd]` click on the variable name to do so. Is there an analogous shortcut or otherwise efficient way to accomplish the same thing in Xcode?

The best I've been able to come up with:

- `[ctrl]+[cmd]` click to navigate to the function definition for `createFooInstance()`, which will indicate the return type `Foo` in its signature. Then  `[ctrl]+[cmd]` click on `Foo` to navigate to *its* definition.
- `[option]` click on `createFooInstance()` to see the declaration window, which indicates `Foo` is the variable's type. While you can't click on the type name here (doing so takes you to documentation, not the source code), you can copy the name and `[shift]+[command]+[o]` paste it to navigate to the source code.

Comment: I didn't even know what I was missing until I started using "jump to type definition" in VSCode. It's a real shame Xcode doesn't have this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode has no equivalent of AppCode's Navigate > Type Declaration feature. I also sorely miss this feature.